# "Expression must have class type error" only occurs when chaining functions c++

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with chaining functions. It is not necessary to do so, but I cannot understand why my code is throwing errors.

header file declaring class:

```
class twoVar {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

public: 
    twoVar() {
        a = 0;
    }
    int accessA() const;
    int accessB() const;
    int mutateA(int &);
    int mutateB(int &);
};
```

source file defining accessor and mutator:

```
int twoVar::accessA() const {
    return a;
}    

int twoVar::accessB() const {
    return b;
}    

int twoVar::mutateA(int & input) {
    a = input;
    return a;
}

int twoVar::mutateB(int & input) {
    b = input; 
    return b;
}
```

Line in main that's throwing error:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;  

    m.mutateA(a).mutateB(b); // chained use of mutator functions - error!
    cout << "m.x = " << m.accessA() << " and m.y = " << m.accessB() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because `mutateA` returns an `int`, you can't call `mutateB` on an `int`.

Comment: Because `m.mutateA(a)` returns int, and int doesn't have the `mutate()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int mutateA(int &);
int mutateB(int &);
```

change this to

```
twoVar& mutateA(int &);
twoVar& mutateB(int &);
```

and make the corresponding changes to the implementations.